# begging letters about the installation of cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Tags: python, cvxopt

when I installed the 'cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl',problems are always going on. I'm using the win7 system, anoconda with python3.6.1. The installation process was held by 'pip install cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' on cmd window. (The path has been switched to the cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl'path).  The cmd window shows  'Successfully installed cvxopt-1.1.9'
      D:\APS>pip install cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
      Processing d:\aps\cvxopt-1.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
      Installing collected packages: cvxopt
      Successfully installed cvxopt-1.1.9
but When the program is executed, it is always reported wrong.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/cvx_opt/linear_program.py", line 1, in 
    from cvxopt import matrix, log, div, spdiag, solvers
  File "C:\MySoftware\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt__init__.py", line 34, in 
    import cvxopt.base
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。

Could you please give me some valuable suggestions? Thank you very much, thank you. Any reply will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The package CVXOPT requires numpy+mkl, so first uninstall the numpy package of anoconda and reinstall numpy+mkl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy, 
then pip install numpy+mkl...whl
next,download cvxopt from
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxopt
finally then pip install CVXOPT...whl
it will work.